# Why do I have to assert the return value of my function explicitly as any?

Tags: typescript

I have this code

```
type ObjectKey = string | number
const ADDIF = '$$fancy__addIf$$'

type ReturnedType<C, K> = C extends true ? K : typeof ADDIF

function addIf<C extends boolean, K extends ObjectKey>(condition: C, key: K): ReturnedType<C, K> {
  if (condition) return key as any
  else return ADDIF as any
}

const b = addIf(true, 1) // b's type will be inferred as 1
```

`b` should be `1` when `addIf` first argument is `true`, and `b` should be `'$$fancy__addIf$$'` when `addIf` first argument is `false`.

It works great, I have no problems in the code at all.

However. I'm still confused, why I have to explicitly say `as any` in the both branches of the `if/else` statement when returning.

When I don't cast them as `any` I get this two errors:

```
Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'ReturnedType<C, K>'.
  Type 'ObjectKey' is not assignable to type 'ReturnedType<C, K>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReturnedType<C, K>'
```

```
Type '"$$fancy__addIf$$"' is not assignable to type 'ReturnedType<C, K>'.
```

Comment: Notice it doesn't actually work for `addIf<true | false, 1>(false, 1)`

Comment: @Bergi, no... 

Comment: @Bergi, can you give an example of where this case could happen

Comment: @Bergi, I'm okay with it since it will default back to be a union, ex:
`const con: any = false; const s = addIf(con, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function addIf<C extends boolean, K extends ObjectKey>(
  condition: C,
  key: K,
): ReturnedType<C, K>
```

As indicated in the comments, the truthiness of `condition` allows us to draw no conclusions about the value `C`. The function constraints `C` to `C extends boolean` and `condition` to have type `C`. So `condition` is certainly either the *value* `true` or the *value* `false`. But that tells us nothing about `C`. If `condition` is `true`, then `C` is either `true` or `true | false`. If `condition` is `false`, then `C` is either `false` or `true | false`. So Typescript isn't going to try to simplify your conditional type, since we haven't concluded anything of value about `C`, only `condition`.

Furthermore, your type signature is actually incorrect. You state

> I'm okay with it since it will default back to be a union

But it will *not* fall back to a union.

```
addIf<true | false, 1>(true, 1)
```

This should, in principle, return `1`, since the condition is `true`. However, look at the declared return type of the function.

```
type ReturnedType<C, K> = C extends true ? K : typeof ADDIF
```

It's a conditional. In our case, `C` is equal to `true | false`, and `true | false extends true` is clearly false, so our conditional branches to the false case. Our return type is `typeof ADDIF`, but our return value is `1`. This is a contradiction.

In your case, I might suggest [*function overloads*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead.

```
function addIf<K extends ObjectKey>(condition: true, key: K): K;
function addIf<K extends ObjectKey>(condition: false, key: K): typeof ADDIF;
function addIf<K extends ObjectKey>(condition: boolean, key: K): K | typeof ADDIF;

function addIf<K extends ObjectKey>(condition: boolean, key: K): K | typeof ADDIF {
  if (condition) return key
  else return ADDIF
}
```

The first line tells us that if `addIf` is called with a condition value whose type is *literally* `true`, then we'll return `K`. The second tells us that if the condition's type is literally `false`, we'll return `typeof ADDIF`. The third tells us that if the condition is an unknown `boolean`, we return a member of the union type. So we've lost type information but it's still fine.

The final body is the implementation.